# RPostgreSQL cannot connect to the server

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I'm trying to access a PostgreSQL database through R.
I tried the following code:

```
   library(RPostgreSQL)
   library(DBI)

   drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

   con = dbConnect(drv, #constructs SQL driver
                   host = MyHost, 
                   port = MyPort,
                   dbname = MyDbname,
                   user = MyUser,
                   password = pw)
```

I already have PostgreSQL installed on my computer. 
With all my credentials being correct, I still get this Error:

```
 Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
     RS-DBI driver: (could not connect [MyUser]@[MyHost] on MyDbname
```

any ideas what causes the problem? [The same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056641/cannot-connect-to-amazon-postgresql-rds-database-on-r-using-rpostgresql)  has no solution yet. Thanks for your help

```
   > sessionInfo()
   R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
   Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
```

Kasia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end, I managed to connect to the database with `RPosgres` package

```
install.packages("devtools") and load them
devtools::install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp")
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/DBI")
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/RPostgres")


con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
             host = MyHost,
             port = MyPort,
             dbname = MyDbname,
             user = MyUser,
             password = pw)


res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 10")
dbFetch(res)
dbClearResult(res)
```